# Jquery how to select images from an other page with the url

Tags: jquery, image, url, iframe, load

I want to display all the images of a page with its url.
The user will be able to able then to choose the right one.

I tried to display the page in an Iframe, but then I have some troubles to manipulate the DOM.

Do you have an other idea to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the external page on a webserver under your control? If yes, you should be able to send the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to enable cross domain Ajax access from the other page.

Otherwise you should set up a so-called "Proxy" script (maybe in PHP) on your server that retrieves the page HTML from the external page and routes it to the browser. The browser will then not complain about any cross domain issue.

Comment: No the page is not on a webserver under my control. Thanks for your help !